# Laravel .htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

Есть стандартный чистый проект Laravel 5.x, установленный на XAMPP и лежащий в директории htdocs(localhost).
Есть .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

и public/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Все работает нормально, но мне нужно, что бы на хостинге проект лежал в подкаталоге "folder". Как при этом будут выглядеть folder/.htaccess и folder/public/.htaccess?

Comment: Нашел ответ на свой вопрос... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url

Answer (score 0):

Этот htaccess разместите снаружи folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) !^folder/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, но суть задачи немного в другом...Мне нужно, по сути, реализовать виртуальные хосты...Т.е. мне надо folder1, folder2, folder3...Но доступа к httpd-vhosts.conf нету....Возможно-ли решить данную проблему с помощью .htaccess файлов в каталогах проектов?

Comment: Уточню...Если положить проект в folder1/ то при обращении к localhost/folder1 я попадаю не на localhost/folder1/public, а на localhost/public/folder1

Comment: в таком случае вам проще настроить соответствущие роуты в файле фреймворка routes/web.php